# Solution of Ax - b (A is square, symmetric, positive-definite )with iterative methods

Tags: optimization, matrix, linear-algebra

I was hoping someone could help me verify my understanding about solving for a system of equations iteratively.

I have a square symmetric, positive-definite matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ and I want to try and find the $x$ that minimizes this equation.

[image]

The system is small enough that I can solve directly (but this will not always be the case).

$$x = A^{-1}b$$

Which (from my understanding) will yield a global result because $A$ is positive-definite. Here is a plot of the $x$ values.

[image]

However, when I try to do this iteratively with `pytorch` I am coming nowhere near close to the solution: Here is my code with loss:

$$ loss = \dfrac{1}{2n}\sum_{i = 1}^n(A^ix - b_i)^2 $$

Where $A^i$ is the $i-th$ row of the matrix $A$.

```py
    x = torch.ones(2540, 1)._requires_grad

    # Set up the Adam optimizer
    optimizer = optim.Adam([x], lr=5e-3)

    # Train the model
    for iteration, i in enumerate(range(300000)):
        # Zero out the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Ax calculation
        Ax = (A @ x).flatten()

        loss = 0.5 * torch.mean(torch.pow(Ax - b, 2))

        # Go through the backward pass and create the gradients
        loss.backward()

        # Step through the optimizer to update the data with the gradients
        optimizer.step()
```

Here is the output of the iterative methods $x$ values:

[image]

So couple of questions here:

1. Is my understanding of the $Ax = b$ incorrect when $A$ is positive-definite? I thought this would have a unique solution so both methods should work. Is that not the case?
2. Does anyone see anything wrong with my logic in my code?

**Update** Here is the loss function: It reaches 8e-6
[image]

Also, adding the eigenvalues of A sorted in descending order:

[image]

Adding conjugate gradient solution:

[image]

Comment: there are specialized methods for solving large linear systems iteratively, you are not gonna use Adam which is a s*itty method for such problem. You can use conjugate gradient algorithm for instance

Comment: Can you show us what the loss looks like as a function of iteration count?

Comment: Hey @JohnMadden I posted the loss 

Comment: Thanks! And if it's not too much of a bother, seeing the eigenvalues plotted would help as well. My suspicion is that $\mathbf{A}$ has a wide spectrum, and as a consequence, running gradient descent effectively won't allow us to move along the directions with small eigenvalues. Indeed, this is why things like CG are more popular than gradient descent for linear system solves, as @Brale suggested.

Comment: @JohnMadden I added those as well! I guess my question is if the solution is unique how can this approximation be so close but nowhere near the unique solution? Where is my gap in logic / knowledge?

Comment: You say that the loss is "nowhere near" the exact solution, but the loss is $8 \times 10^{-6}$. That seems very close, especially considering that the default in pytorch is to use single-precision floats.

Comment: The plots of $x$ do not match - I would expect them to match with the loss at $8 x 10^{-6}$

Comment: @Sycorax, RDizzl3, the point is that they match wrt the metric on $\mathbb{R}^N$ induced by $\mathbf{A}$; they need not be anywhere close in the Euclidean sense.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I feel like I am not understanding why that is the case but to just add a little more context $x$ itself has a physics based meaning. So if they are not the same in the euclidean sense then I cannot use the solution. The whole idea I am trying to sort out is to build $x$ is various different ways in particular using iterative methods. As a matter of fact conjugate gradient gave me exactly a matching solution and I added that plot as well. I will have to dive into the mechanics now to understand why. I have a lot to learn!

Comment: I do appreciate the comments and the help this has already helped me start exploring other directions that I didn't know about.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something but have you tried LBFGS? PyTorch does have it and should work as it should approximate the Hessian.

Comment: Hi @usεr11852 yes thank you for the comment. I started to explore LFBGS after this conversation and in some cases I was able to get the $x$ I was looking for that I showed above with CG but it also seems very sensitive to the starting $x_0$.